# How to permit inserting a character only leftmost position of edittext android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have implemented a dialpad where I don't want to permit user to insert "+" inside edittext except left position of edittext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `InputFilter` for your requirement. Try out the following code:

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
                public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                        Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
                    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
                        if (source.charAt(i) == '+' && i!=start) { 
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid Input",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            return "";
                        }
                    }
                    return null;
                }

            };

editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer is great but need to return 
source.toString().substring(0, source.length()-1) 
instead of ""

Comment: It's just the filter for your `EditText`. This will `return ""` if user put + elsewhere rather than the start. If user put `+` properly you can do this - `edittext.getText().toString().substring(0, source.length()-1)` later.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably make use of `TextWatcher`. Something like the code below should serve the purpose:

```
txtNumbers.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // Do the magic here

        int positionOfPlus = txtNumbers.getText().toString().indexOf("+");

        if (positionOfPlus != -1 && positionOfPlus != 0) {
            txtNumbers.setText("+" + txtNumbers.getText().toString().replace("+", ""));
        }
    }
});
```

For more information on `TextWatcher`, read here: [TextWatcher | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code snippet to do the trick:

editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

```
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                  int before, int count) {
            // here you can check for '+' sign, and then you can remove additional '=' sign from it.
        }
    });
```

hope this will help you.